# why is only metric tensor used to shift indices?

Tags: tensors

From what basic things I noticed about tensor calculus any fundamental tensor would be good enough to shift indices. What makes metric tensor in such cases so special?

Comment: symmetry at calculating distances perhaps?

Comment: In the moment you decide to use _any_ particular tensor to shift indices (as long and it is symmetric and non-degenerate) then that tensor becomes the metric of your space.